# Code to get product image, availability and description in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woo commerce project in which I want to show product image, availability, description and add to card.

I used the short code `[product id="1234"]`, but it shows the whole product details - I just want to show the product image, availability and description.

Is there any short code or other code to get them?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php 
    $product_DI = 1234; //Product ID
    $pro = new WC_Product($product_DI);

    echo "<b>price: </b>".$pro->get_price();      /// Get price
    echo "<b>availability Stock: </b>".$pro->get_total_stock();   //Get number of  availability
    echo "<b>availability Status: </b>".$pro->is_in_stock( );  //Get availability Status
    echo "<b>Image: </b>".$pro->get_image($size = 'shop_thumbnail');  //Get Image
    echo "<b>Title: </b>".$pro->get_title();  //Get Title
    echo "<b>description: </b>".$pro->get_post_data()->post_excerpt;  //Get description 

?>
```

Comment: It's fine but I want to show product image, availability, description, product-code and add to cart in my single post and PHP code is nit working in post. then how would I show them in my post. for example I can show add to cart using [add_to_cart id="123"] code and product by [product id="123" ] but it does not show the description and availability so how can I show it in my post

Comment: create shortcode.for this code.
read more for the  product-code.. etc.
http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Comment: Thanks @DevDanidhariya, that came in quite useful today.

Comment: it my pleasure @Nathan.

Comment: This code is working for me, but I'm getting a html string very hard to parse

Comment: @mthama why html string very hard to parse.??